# z-index not working properly on ios devices

Tags: css, animation, z-index

I am working on a preloader animation on other devices everything is working fine except the ios browser...

initially, the polaroid image should be at the back first, (it should look like it was printing a polaroid image from the camera), after that it flips then positions on top of the camera then scales to 0 for the outro of the polaroid.

[**here is the codepen codes**](https://codepen.io/lhorainemarinas/pen/RVzoGM?editors=1100)

```css
.preloader {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.stack,
.cameras {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-20%);
}

.cameras {
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-85%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-85%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-85%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-85%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-85%);
}

.preloader .cameras span img.camera-img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.cameras span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.cameras span .polaroid {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  max-width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  animation: ikot infinite 5s linear;
}

@keyframes ikot {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    bottom: 150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  66% {
    bottom: 180%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  68% {
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  80% {
    bottom: -150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  82% {
    bottom: -120%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  86% {
    bottom: -55%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  90% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
  }
  95% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ikot {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    bottom: 150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  66% {
    bottom: 180%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  68% {
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  80% {
    bottom: -150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  82% {
    bottom: -120%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  86% {
    bottom: -55%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  90% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
  }
  95% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes ikot {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    bottom: 150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  66% {
    bottom: 180%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  68% {
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  80% {
    bottom: -150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  82% {
    bottom: -120%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  86% {
    bottom: -55%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  90% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
  }
  95% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes ikot {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    bottom: 150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  66% {
    bottom: 180%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  68% {
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  80% {
    bottom: -150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  82% {
    bottom: -120%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  86% {
    bottom: -55%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  90% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
  }
  95% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes ikot {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    bottom: 150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  66% {
    bottom: 180%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  68% {
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-80deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  80% {
    bottom: -150%;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-140deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  82% {
    bottom: -120%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  86% {
    bottom: -55%;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
    transform: rotateX(-40deg) translateZ(2px);
  }
  90% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
    transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(2px) scale(1.8);
  }
  95% {
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8);
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

.preloader .cameras span.current {
  display: block;
}

.preloader .cameras span {
  display: none;
  perspective: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="stack">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/jLCafv/stack.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="cameras">
    <span class="current">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/i5Dy0v/q10.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJE8YF/q10_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ebc97a/mini8.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/e5iVfv/mini8_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/epVU7a/mini9.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cct7Sa/mini9_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hBup7a/mini25.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iaOJYF/mini25_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fAXbna/mini70.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hNxqfv/mini70_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eu8Gna/mini90.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/heNj7a/mini90_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fLYStF/wide300.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cvQAfv/wide300_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
    <span>
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dP3hSa/hellokitty.png" class="camera-img">
         <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fW0Mna/hellokitty_sample.jpg" class="polaroid">
       </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: The iOS browser is Safari.

Comment: Also, you never explain what's _wrong_.

Comment: when using safari, initially the polaroid is on top of the camera which is wrong... the polaroid should be initially at the back of the camera... @JaredFarrish

Comment: Aaaaaand we never hear of Jared again